# I can't use pandoc for select epubs?

Tags: powershell, command-line, pandoc, epub

I have some epubs that I'm trying to merge with pandoc. There's nothing wrong with the epubs themselves, but pandoc always throws me the following error when I try to do anything with it:
 `not found in reftable`

There's nothing wrong with the epubs themselves, but I think the issue is that they're using a different kind of style?

Does anyone know of a way to bypass this issue?

If I use ebook-convert to convert the epub to txt, it's perfectly functional. I want to be able to use pandoc because I'm trying to merge all epubs within a directory.

PowerShell/Command Line input:

```
pandoc (get-item *.epub).FullName -o output.epub
pandoc -f epub -t plain --wrap none -o filename.txt filename.epub
```

Both of which throw the same  `not found in reftable` error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please report it at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/new; include a minimal reproducible example if possible.

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks for the heads up! Not sure how to add a reproducible example since github doesn't support epub uploads but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Epub files are just fancy zip files: you can rename your files to `.zip`; I think those are allowed by GitHub.